# How to Compile and Install qTox from GitHub on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, compiling, qtox

I tried to look at similar threads. I don't understand the answers.
How do I simply install this?

The recommended way would be to build from source, download https://github.com/qTox/qTox and run `simple_make.sh`

I don't understand how to run `make.sh`, where to direct it at etc. This OS is so darn difficult to use.

Answer (score 3):

First install git with

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Then clone the project into your destination:

```
git clone https://github.com/qTox/qTox
git clone https://github.com/toktok/c-toxcore.git toxcore
```

Install dependencies packages

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake libavcodec-dev libavdevice-dev \
  libavfilter-dev libavutil-dev libexif-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev \
  libgtk2.0-dev libopenal-dev libqrencode-dev libqt5opengl5-dev libqt5svg5-dev \
  libsqlcipher-dev libswresample-dev libswscale-dev libxss-dev qrencode qt5-default \
  qttools5-dev-tools qttools5-dev libtool autotools-dev automake checkinstall check \
  libopus-dev libvpx-dev libsodium-dev libqt5concurrent5
```

and now you are ready to compile:

**1. Compiling toxcore**

```
cd toxcore
cmake .
make -j $(nproc)
sudo make install
echo '/usr/local/lib/' | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/locallib.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

**2. Compile qTox**

```
cd ../qTox
cmake .
make -j $(nproc)
```

Now you can start the fresh compiled qTox with

```
./qTox
```

---

3. Alternativley download compiled package and unpack it
   ====

Create a folder qtox in your home directory by

```
mkdir ~/qtox
```

then change into it:

```
cd ~/qtox
```

Download qTox from the tox.chat homepage using the wget command:

```
wget https://build.tox.chat/job/toxic_build_linux_x86-64_release/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/toxic_build_linux_x86-64_release.tar.xz
```

Uncompress the downloaded file with

```
unxz toxic_build_linux_x86-64_release.tar.xz 
tar xvf toxic_build_linux_x86-64_release.tar
```

Now you are ready to run qtox with

```
 ./run_toxic.sh
```

Comment: Pls remove mega.nz link and point to official website. Users should not download anything from unofficial website and install.

Comment: @EdwardTorvalds I note that the mega.nz download link is a pretty old version:  qtox_201608051313~34aa905_amd64 .deb . And I also note that Ubuntu from Focal Fossa (20.04) onwards packages qtox anyway. I will take it upon myself to remove the 'download deb' section in light of this...